# Unable to resolve ansible_user variable

Tags: ansible

## Setup

1. Passwords, not keys are used for ssh
2. The target is accessed via the bastion host (ssh -> bastion -> target)
3. The password is kept in an encrypted file that is accessed based on the `ansible_user` name
4. When decrypted, the password is `bastion`

## Command

`$ ansible -i ./inventory/debug -m debug -a 'var=foo' -kKu ansible all`

## Command Output

```sh
target | FAILED! => {
    "msg": "The field 'ssh_common_args' has an invalid value, which includes an undefined variable. The error was: 'ansible_user' is undefined"
}
bastion | SUCCESS => {
    "foo": "-o ProxyCommand=\"sshpass -p bastion ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -W %h:%p -q ansible@3.21.247.xxx.\""
}
```

## Problem

1. The password is correctly accessed and resolved for `foo` for `bastion`, but `foo` cannot be resolved for the target host.

## The inventory file (called "debug")

```yaml
all:
  vars:
    env: 3.21.247.xxx
    password: "{{lookup('file', inventory_dir + '/../users/' + ansible_user + '.yml')}}"
    foo: "-o ProxyCommand=\"sshpass -p {{password}} ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -W %h:%p -q ansible@{{env}}.\""
  children:
    bastions:
      hosts:
        bastion:
          ansible_host: "{{ env }}"
    nv:
       children:
         targets:
           hosts:
             target:
               ansible_host:  10.0.3.209
           vars:
              ansible_ssh_common_args: "{{ foo }}"
```

Comment: Please make this an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: ... and I basically cannot reproduce your problem. If I use the `-u` option to `ansible(-playbook)` or if I add a `remote_user` option in my play, the var is always defined. The only way to get it undefined is to totally skip those declarations. Note that for `localhost` the var is always defined and is the current localhost shell user, whatever you declare anywhere (unless you change the default `local` connection).

Comment: I updated the query to make it more in line with MCVE.  Are you using the -kK options when you cannot reproduce the issue?

Comment: https://gist.github.com/zeitounator/6168991050065ca2c371e99d8d91a2d6

Comment: @Zeitounator Thank you.  That helped my further clarify my issue.  I've updated the question/problem accordingly

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use jinja2 expansion inside jinja2 expansion. Try:

```
"{{lookup('file', inventory_dir + '/../users/' + ansible_user + '.yml')}}"
```